# Download a digital product at woocommerce checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm selling an ebook via woocommerce. When the customer is done completing checkout via PayPal, and they return to my site they are taken to a order confirmation page with basic order details. I'd like to allow them to download the ebook right there on the confirmation page.

Is this possible?

Comment: By Order confirmation page, do you refer to thank you page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When customer makes successful payment and returns at your site, woocommerce by default provides virtual/downloadable products to customer.

Make sure, you have selected both of these options.

[image]